# ForeignKeyAttribute Not Working MVC3 EF5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have these classes:

```
public class SystemRequirements : DbEntity
{
   public string OS {get;set;}
}

public class Application : DbEntity
{
   public string Name {get;set;}

   public virtual SystemRequirements MinimumSystemRequirements {get;set;}
   public Guid MinimumSystemRequirementsId {get;set;}

   public virtual SystemRequirements RecommendedSystemRequirements {get;set;}
   public Guid RecommendedSystemRequirementsId {get;set;}
}
```

I got an error saying: Introducting Foreign Key Constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.

`DbEntity` is an abstract class containing the Primary Key. `[Key] public Guid Id {get;set;}`

So, I changed `Application` to:

```
public class Application : DbEntity
{
   public string Name {get;set;}

   public virtual SystemRequirements MinimumSystemRequirements {get;set;}
   [ForeignKey("MinimumSystemRequirements")]
   public Guid MinimumSystemRequirementsId {get;set;}

   public virtual SystemRequirements RecommendedSystemRequirements {get;set;}
   [ForeignKey("RecommendedSystemRequirements")]
   public Guid RecommendedSystemRequirementsId {get;set;}
}
```

So my question is why doesn't this work? I even tried putting a reference to `Application` in `SystemRequirements`, that didn't work?

Please don't trawl this post for spelling mistakes. My code is fine on VS, I copy and paste rather type out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heyyyyy good news. I figured out the issue!

I remember back in the day (couple of months ago) I was told that in order to enable `Cascade On Delete` using `Attributes` in Code First you must do this:

```
public Guid CascadeOnId {get;set;}
public virtual Cascade CascadeOn {get;set;}
```

However before I knew that I was always using this:

```
public virtual Cascade CascadeOff {get;set;}
```

The reason I'm getting the cyclic delete, is because the first example will delete the HDD if it exists, but the HDD must always exist for the second instance of it, example:

```
public Guid FirstCascadeId {get;set;}
public virtual Cascade FirstCascade {get;set;}

public Guid SecondCascadeId {get;set;}
public virtual Cascade SecondCascade {get;set;}
```

So, entity framework is worrying that if you delete a cascade entity, it must delete it's associated parent, in deleting a parent you must delete all associated cascades. Which is where the cycle begins. I hope I'm making some sort of sense.

In order to turn `Cascade On Delete` off, you mustn't specify a `Guid` Id relating to that virtual. So In order to make the above work, you use:

```
public virtual Cascade FirstCascade {get;set;}
public virtual Cascade SecondCascade {get;set;}
```

You can turn on the first `Cascade On Delete` if you want, just make sure one of them hasn't got it and it works fine :)

I found the answer by using Model First, and then getting a massive glowing bulb above my head :P

Comment: Interesting..do you have some documentation of this that you could link to?

Comment: No, I just remember doing it that is all. Try it out it's really easy to set up, I used the model `Computer` and `Hdd` where the `Computer` has to references (navigation properties) to `Hdd`, then layout `Computer` like the scenarios in my answer

Comment: I found out that you can also make the Id properties nullable. Never realized that. Doing that, you will still have the benefits of foreign key associations. However, I would prefer the explicit (fluent) mapping in stead of relying on these hidden features.

Comment: you know what, I actually tried to look for a Nullable attribute, is it an attribute? How do you make them nullable. That was the first thing I tried, because after doing the Model First, I could see that by making them nullable there were no complaints.

Answer (score 0):

`SystemRequirements` probably needs to have the `MinimumSystemRequirementsID` and `RecommendedSystemRequirmentsID` fields.  My understanding of EF FK relationships is it looks at the model for the value of the Element you are calling a FK and then uses that for linking.

Try this:

```
public class SystemRequirements : DbEntity
{
   public string OS {get;set;}
   public Guid MinimumSystemRequirementsId {get;set;}
   public Guid RecommendedSystemRequirementsId {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I believe I got both the virtual class and the Id linking them together

Comment: You have virtual in the `Application` model and the FK there as well, but the FK is just 'pointing' to the value to be used within `SystemRequirements`...think of it like two tables..you are trying to set a foreign key, which needs to point to a key in the other table...I know you have `id` in all `DbEntity` but my experience has required the FK match the field in the model I'm trying to link..thus `MinimumSystemRequirementsId` and `RecommendedSystemRequirementsId`

Comment: So are you saying to add the FK to the SystemRequirements class or modifying DbEntity

Comment: Add to SystemRequirements, like in my answer. Leave your Application model as it is.

Comment: but that would weirdly make a field redundant at any given point. It sounds like it could work, just sounds a bit weird.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell EF that (at least) one of the associations between `Application` and `SystemRequirements` has no cascading delete, for instance:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Application>().HasRequired(a => a.MinimumSystemRequirements)
    .WithMany().HasForeignKey(a => a.MinimumSystemRequirementsId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

(In the context's overload of `OnModelCreating`).

Comment: I prefer attributes to fluent api

Comment: There is no attribute equivalent to this :(

Comment: Do you need HasRequired? cause I don't need any requireds in what I'm doing.

Comment: No, you can use `HasOptional()`.